# Implementing alternative forms of LDA

Tags: python, r, nlp, text-mining, lda

I am using Latent Dirichlet Allocation with a corpus of news data from six different sources. I am interested in topic evolution, emergence, and want to compare how the sources are alike and different from each other over time. I know that there are a number of modified LDA algorithms such as the Author-Topic model, Topics Over Time, and so on.

My issue is that very few of these alternate model specifications are implemented in any standard format. A few are available in Java, but most exist as conference papers only. What is the best way to go about implementing some of these algorithms on my own? I am fairly proficient in R and jags, and can stumble around in Python when given long enough. I am willing to write the code, but I don't really know where to start and I don't know C or Java. Can I build a model in JAGS or Python just having the formulas from the manuscript? If so, can someone point me at an example of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: I have a friend who literally just had to do this about a week ago. He ultimately implemented his own version of the collapsed Gibbs sampler in Python and C. Depending on the size of your data, you may have no choice but to use faster languages. At any rate, I'm going to see if I can get this friend to post about how he solved this problem.

Comment: Have you had a look at the `R` packages `topicmodels` and `lda`? There is also a bit of chatter about this on http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Ben Yes -- I have used both packages, but the actual algorithmic portion is already compiled in both cases which doesn't lend itself to extension. The lda package is excellent and fast but I am also looking for some flexibility without having to learn C or Java while writing my dissertation.

Comment: @Trey, yes I see what you mean. MALLET might be a better bet, though it's Java-based and you say you would prefer to avoid that...

Comment: @EMS Any luck with your friend?

Comment: I posted something below. IN addition, you may want to look at ways to make this work with PyCUDA on the GPU. I'm not sure that will be easy, but may mitigate some of the speed problems.

Answer (score 4):

My friend's response is below, pardon the language please.

> First I wrote up a Python implementation of the collapsed Gibbs sampler seen here (http://www.pnas.org/content/101/suppl.1/5228.full.pdf+html) and fleshed out here (http://cxwangyi.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/llt.pdf). This was slow as balls.
>
> Then I used a Python wrapping of a C implementation of this paper (http://books.nips.cc/papers/files/nips19/NIPS2006_0511.pdf). Which is fast as f*ck, but the results are not as great as one would see with NMF.
>
> But NMF implementations I've seen, with scitkits, and even with the scipy sparse-compatible recently released NIMFA library, they all blow the f*ck up on any sizable corpus. My new white whale is a sliced, distributed implementation of the thing. This'll be non-trivial.

Answer (score 3):

In Python, do you know of [PyMC](http://pymcmc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)? It's flexible in specifying both the model and the fitting algorithm.

Also, when starting with R and JAGS, there is [this tutorial on "Using JAGS in R with the rjags Package"](http://www.r-bloggers.com/using-jags-in-r-with-the-rjags-package/) together with [a collection of examples](http://www.r-bloggers.com/using-jags-in-r-with-the-rjags-package/).